# Query for master in Postgres replication

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to query for the master, from a slave PostgreSQL server that has been set up with server replication.

From a slave, I can:

```
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()
```

And this will give me a 't' result if I'm on a slave and an 'f' result on the master, which is step one.

Next, I'd like to run a query that gives me some information about the master that it's replicating.  Preferably an IP address or hostname.

For the record, I can query the master with:

```
SELECT * from pg_stat_replication
```

And this will give me information about slaves.  I am hoping that there is a reciprocal method for querying a slave.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way through SQL to get master information from a slave, as Craig said.

One solution I came up once was to use `pg_read_file` to get the contents of `recovery.conf` file, as:

```
SELECT pg_read_file('recovery.conf');
```

With that information, we can easily parse it using a regular expression to get all config/values. I used the following to get it done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (rm[1]) rm[1] AS name, coalesce(replace(rm[4], '''''', ''''), rm[2]) AS setting FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER() rn, confs, regexp_matches(confs, '^[\s]*([a-z_]+)[\s]*=[\s]*([A-Za-z_\200-\377]([-A-Za-z_0-9\200-\377._:/]*)|''(([^''\n]|\\.|'''')*)'')') AS rm
FROM regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('recovery.conf'), '\n') AS confs
) AS recovery_confs
ORDER BY rm[1], rn DESC;
```

With that, it is just a matter of choosing your config:

```
WITH recconfs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (rm[1]) rm[1] AS name, coalesce(replace(rm[4], '''''', ''''), rm[2]) AS setting FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER() rn, confs, regexp_matches(confs, '^[\s]*([a-z_]+)[\s]*=[\s]*([A-Za-z_\200-\377]([-A-Za-z_0-9\200-\377._:/]*)|''(([^''\n]|\\.|'''')*)'')') AS rm
    FROM regexp_split_to_table(pg_read_file('recovery.conf'), '\n') AS confs
    ) AS recovery_confs
    ORDER BY rm[1], rn DESC
)
SELECT setting FROM recconfs WHERE name = 'primary_conninfo';
```

The regex was adapted from PG's source file `guc-file.l`, but I did not used all the possible variants, which means that it will only work for strings (unquoted or with single quotes), which is Ok for `primary_conninfo`.

There are, in my opnion, two problems with this approach:

1. I don't guarantee this regex is **really** 100% perfect, anyone can see a mistake?
2. Only a superuser can use `pg_read_file`, but that is not really a problem, as it is expected or you can wrap it on a function (I did that, because I wanted a non-superuser to check it, in my case was a `REPLICATION` user).

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!  pg_read_file() is sufficient for my needs.  I was not aware that such a function existed.  Problem solved!  I think my only issue will be user permissions to access the function, but this was going to be a problem regardless.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. About the permission problem, you can create another function as a superuser owner and with `SECURITY DEFINER`, then just grant execution of that to other users.

Answer (score 2):

At present (Pg 9.2 and 9.3beta) as far as I know no mechanism for asking a replica about its master is provided. All the replica knows is how to connect to the master via settings in `recovery.conf`, which are not accessible from SQL.

There's been work ongoing to merge `recovery.conf` into `postgresql.conf`, which would make it possible to see information about the upstream server from `pg_catalog.pg_settings` - assuming the security issues with that get worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I can get master's IP address extracting a regexp from `pg_stat_wal_receiver.conninfo`:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(conninfo,'host=([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})'))[1] AS master_addr
  FROM pg_stat_wal_receiver;
```